# SYSTEM: denied request 44 in Minix

Tags: linux, bsd, minix

I get "SYSTEM: denied request 44 from 109894" when trying to execute my own code in Minix 3.2. I typed over the code and the makefile so there could be some typos. The program compiles fine however.

My c file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <minix/syslib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 printf("test");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

My makefile:

```
PROG = helloproc
SRC = helloproc.c

MAN=

.include <bsd.prog.mk>
```

Minix uses the BSD compilation platform (hence the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently running the application somewhere other than /usr/srcs/drivers let it be run as a normal program instead of a driver.